# How to resolve 'Unsupported settings' error for 'java.lang.reflect.Executable' after upgrading to Java 17 with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, java-17

I'm encountering the org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unsupported settings with this type 'java.lang.reflect.Executable' error when upgrading from Java 8 to Java 17. This error occurs when trying to mock the Executable class using Mockito.

Here is the code snippet causing the error:

```
Executable executable = mock(Executable.class);
```

The intention of this code snippet is to create a mock object of the Executable class. However, I'm receiving this error after upgrading to Java 17.

How can I resolve this error? What could be the issues with the relevant code? I would appreciate your assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: `Executable` allows exactly two subclasses, `Constructor` and `Method`. It was never foreseen to have a different subclass and it’s not clear what you are about to test by creating a mock for a thing that shouldn’t exist.

Comment: To further support Holger's comment, [`Executable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html) has been [sealed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409) as of Java 17.